# No DataContext and Tapped property in New Map Control - Windows 10

Tags: c#, maps, windows-8.1, uwp, windows-10-universal

I've a question about the new map control in Windows 10 UWP. I need to add a map layer that will contain a set of polygons, each polygon has to hold some data bound to it, and I want to know how to handle tap event on the polygon to display the details related to it. But there is no property DataContext, and no event Tapped in the MapPolygon class. how can we achieve it?

Comment: Did you already tried to follow this example? http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.be/2015/08/windows-10-maps-part-3-querying-map.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define Polygon within the data template and you can bind polygon’s Path to a List of BasicGeoposition. For the tapped event, you can get the geolocation from mapElementClick event when the user taps on the Polygon.

I tried the following code to get the tap event from a polygon and it seems to work

1) Creating the polygon

```
var polygon = new MapPolygon(); 
polygon.FillColor = Color.FromArgb(80, 255, 0, 0);   
polygon.StrokeColor = Colors.Red;    
polygon.StrokeThickness = 15;
```

2)  Setting the path for polygon

```
List<BasicGeoposition> positions = new List<BasicGeoposition>();
       positions.Add(new BasicGeoposition { Latitude = 25.251231, Longitude = 55.305957 });

       positions.Add(new BasicGeoposition { Latitude = 25.251105, Longitude = 55.306445 });
       positions.Add(new BasicGeoposition { Latitude = 25.249977, Longitude = 55.306091 });
       positions.Add(new BasicGeoposition { Latitude = 25.250392, Longitude = 55.304441 });
       positions.Add(new BasicGeoposition { Latitude = 25.250748, Longitude = 55.304661 });
       positions.Add(new BasicGeoposition { Latitude = 25.250481, Longitude = 55.305726 });
       polygon.Path = new Geopath(positions);
```

3)  Add the polygon to MapElemetns

> `myMap.MapElements.Add(polygon);`

4)  Set the map center and zoom level

```
myMap.Center = new Geopoint((new BasicGeoposition { Latitude =
25.251231, Longitude = 55.305957 }));    
myMap.ZoomLevel = 18;
```

5)     Add the MapElementClick event for handling tap on the polygon

```
myMap.MapElementClick += MyMap_MapElementClick;
private void MyMap_MapElementClick(MapControl sender, MapElementClickEventArgs args)
        {
          // add your code to position the canvas (pop up) and display it here
        }
```